# Quartus error (12006) Node instance instantiates undefined entity

Tags: entity, vhdl, fpga, quartus

I'm trying to compile the sample code for the BCD adder from the book with Quartus II 13.1.

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
USE ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

ENTITY bcdadder IS
    PORT(
        c0      : IN STD_LOGIC;
        a,b : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(4 downto 1);
        c4      : OUT STD_LOGIC;
        sum : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(4 downto 1));
END bcdadder;

ARCHITECTURE    adder OF bcdadder IS
-- component declaration
COMPONENT add4par IS
PORT(
    c0  : IN STD_LOGIC;
    a,b: IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(4 downto 1);
    c4 : OUT STD_LOGIC;
    sum: OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(4 downto 1));
END COMPONENT;

SIGNAL c4_bin   : STD_LOGIC;
SIGNAL c4_bcd   : STD_LOGIC;
SIGNAL sum_bin  : std_LOGIC_VECTOR(4 downto 1);
SIGNAL binary   : std_LOGIC_VECTOR(5 downto 1);
SIGNAL a_bcd    : std_LOGIC_VECTOR(4 downto 1);
SIGNAL c0_bcd   : std_LOGIC;

BEGIN
--Instantinate 4-bit adder (binary sum)
    add_bin: add4par
        PORT MAP ( c0 => c0_bcd,
                      a  => a,
                      b  => b,
                      c4 => c4_bin,
                      sum => sum_bin);
                     
--Instantinate 4-bit adder (binary-BCD converter)
    converter: add4par
        PORT MAP (c0  => c0_bcd,
                     a   => a_bcd,
                     b    => sum_bin,
                     sum => sum);
                     
--BCD carry input (code converter has no input carry)
    c0_bcd <= '0';

--Concancenate binary carry and sum for comparison functions
    binary <= c4_bin & sum_bin;
--Generate a BCD carry for number from 10 to 19
    --If there is a BCD carry, add 6 to sum
    --If no BCD carry, add 0
PROCESS(binary)
BEGIN   
    --This comparison requires std_logic_unsigned package
    IF (binary >= "01010" and binary <= "10011") THEN
        c4_bcd <= '1';
        a_bcd  <= "0110";
    ELSE
        c4_bcd <= '0';
        a_bcd  <= "0000";
    END IF;
END PROCESS;

--Map c4 port to internal BCD carry
c4 <= c4_bcd;

END adder;
```

This are the errors I get

> Error (12006): Node instance "add_bin" instantiates undefined entity "add4par"
>
> Error (12006): Node instance "converter" instantiates undefined entity "add4par"
>
> Error: Quartus II 64-Bit Analysis & Synthesis was unsuccessful. 2 errors, 0 warnings

I used to solve this problem by creating a separate entities instead of components and it worked, but now I'm required to use components.
None of the solutions suggested by Altera helped.

Any advice please.

Comment: Have you included the file that describes `add4par` in the project?

Comment: You don't detect [overflow](http://i.stack.imgur.com/NzBnp.png) should your summed binary coded decimal input values exceed 19. Unlike constrained numerical types a binary representation can hold any valid binary value. Your VHDL code analyzed after providing an add4par entity/architecture pair to the working directory.

Comment: @user1155120 Could you please show me the code of  entity/architecture pair you used to test my code?

Comment: @scary_jeff Thanks, that's true I forgot to include the file. It works now

Comment: The entity/architecture pair [bcdadder_tb](http://i.stack.imgur.com/JgQ2a.jpg).